# Cannot set property 'color' of undefined inheritance angular4

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a class (object) ClassA that inherit from ClassB

```
export ClassA {
    name: string;
    phone: string;
}

export ClassC {
   color: string;
}

export ClassB extends ClassA {
    classC: ClassC;
    list: string[];
}
```

in my component I declare

```
export class AppComponent {

    classB: ClassB;

    constructor() {
        this.classB = new ClassB();
    }

    search() {
        this.classB.classC.color = 'green';
    }
}
```

when I call search method I have error when setting name attribute

Answer (score 1):

Only `classC`'s type is defined. It has to be initialised. You can do like this.

```
export ClassB extends ClassA{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.classC = new classC()
    }  
    classC:ClassC;
    list:string[];
}
```

and `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` has to be exported as classes.

Comment: I added the constructor with classC initialized but I got the same error I added also the super(); for ClassA

Comment: ClassA and ClassB  and ClassC has to be exported as classes.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ClassB` class, you declare a member named `classC` of type `ClassC`, but you never initialize it.  Try this:

```
export ClassB extends ClassA {
    classC: ClassC;
    list: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.classC = new ClassC();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the constructor with classC initialized but I got the same error I added also the super(); for ClassA